# Commons Fileupload Security manager enabled

Tags: apache, tomcat, wso2

I am  trying to upload a file to the database in the form of a blob during which the file upload program writes a temporary file to the disk.

I'm using Wso2 Stratos application server (based on Tomcat) is preventing such temp file to be written to the disk due to security reasons. I have attached the stack trace of the error.

I'm using Apache Commons Fileupload Library. Here is my upload class http://paste.org/47685 and The error is throwing from line 57. I need to avoid writing temp files How can I solve this problem?

This is my error log

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission F:\W
SO2ST~1.2\bin\..\tmp\upload_4e2fd9dc_1368bb5a330__7ffa_00000002.tmp write)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:962)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReache
d(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(
ThresholdingOutputStream.java:224)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(Threshold
ingOutputStream.java:128)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:103)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadB
ase.java:366)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(
ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at controler.UploadDocumentServlet.doPost(UploadDocumentServlet.java:62)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:273
)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270
)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:3
05)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.
java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(Applicatio
nFilterChain.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilt
erChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilt
erChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonS
tuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcesso
r.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.pr
ocess(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:705)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this temp file issue.
By default  DiskFileItemFactory() size is 10,240 byts, it a file exceed this amount it will create a temp file for storing the file. So that's the bug my files are more than 10,240 byts size. So by increasing the size of the filefactory object solves the problem. refer this link
http://www.techiepark.com/tutorials/file-upload-using-java

Answer (score 1):

So you don't have permissions to write to `F:\W
SO2ST~1.2\tmp\upload_4e2fd9dc_1368bb5a330__7ffa_00000002.tmp`, do you have permissions to write to any directory on the file system? (if that tmp folder doesn't exist then that might be your problem)

If so you just need to confgure the tmp directory of your `factory` to be a directory you can write to (there should a tmp folder for the active user where you can store files, like C:\Documents and Settings\MyUser\Temp, or something like that)

- [DiskFileItemFactory.setRepository(File)](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html#setRepository%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: No I don't have permission to write to any directory of the file system. can use a memory buffer without using a temp file for this operation, If so how can I do it for line 57 here http://paste.org/47685 List items = upload.parseRequest(request);